# TrimEnd Equivalent in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, trim

I have column (Numbers) which has values as follows:

```
1,2,3
1,2,3,
1,2,3,,,
1,2,3,,,,,,
```

I want to Trim all the Commas at the end of string, So that result would be

```
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
```

I have tried below Query but by this we can remove only one last comma

```
DECLARE @String as VARCHAR(50)
SET @String='1,2,3,4,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,'

SELECT CASE WHEN right(rtrim(@String),1) = ',' then substring(rtrim(@String),1,len(rtrim(@String))-1)
    ELSE @String 
    END AS TruncString
```

How can I remove all the commas at the end of string?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this using:

```
LEFT(Numbers, LEN(Numbers) - (PATINDEX('%[^,]%', REVERSE(Numbers)) - 1))
```

The premise of this is you first reverse the string using [`REVERSE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180040.aspx):

```
REVERSE(Numbers) --> ,,,,,,3,2,1
```

You then find the position of the first character that is not a comma using [`PATINDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) and the pattern match `[^,]`:

```
PATINDEX('%[^,]%', REVERSE(Numbers)) --> ,,,,,,3,2,1 = 7
```

Then you can use the length of the string using [`LEN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx), to get the inverse position, i.e. if the position of the first character that is not a comma is 7 in the reversed string, and the length of the string is 10, then you need the first 4 characters of the string. You  then use [`SUBSTRING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) to extract the relevant part

A full example would be

```
SELECT  Numbers,
        Reversed = REVERSE(Numbers),
        Position = PATINDEX('%[^,]%', REVERSE(Numbers)),
        TrimEnd = LEFT(Numbers, LEN(Numbers) - (PATINDEX('%[^,]%', REVERSE(Numbers)) - 1))
FROM    (VALUES 
            ('1,2,3'), 
            ('1,2,3,'), 
            ('1,2,3,,,'), 
            ('1,2,3,,,,,,'), 
            ('1,2,3,,,5,,,'), 
            (',,1,2,3,,,5,,')
        ) t (Numbers);
```

---

**EDIT**

In response to an edit, that had some errors in the syntax, the below has functions to trim the start, and trim both sides of commas:

```
SELECT  Numbers,
        Reversed = REVERSE(Numbers),
        Position = PATINDEX('%[^,]%', REVERSE(Numbers)),
        TrimEnd = LEFT(Numbers, LEN(Numbers) - (PATINDEX('%[^,]%', REVERSE(Numbers)) - 1)),
        TrimStart = SUBSTRING(Numbers, PATINDEX('%[^,]%', Numbers), LEN(Numbers)),
        TrimBothSide = SUBSTRING(Numbers, 
                                    PATINDEX('%[^,]%', Numbers), 
                                    LEN(Numbers) - 
                                        (PATINDEX('%[^,]%', REVERSE(Numbers)) - 1) - 
                                        (PATINDEX('%[^,]%', Numbers) - 1)
                                    )
FROM    (VALUES 
            ('1,2,3'), 
            ('1,2,3,'), 
            ('1,2,3,,,'), 
            ('1,2,3,,,,,,'), 
            ('1,2,3,,,5,,,'), 
            (',,1,2,3,,,5,,')
        ) t (Numbers);
```

Comment: This is the most complete answer I've ever seen on this subject. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 2):

Because there are multiple occurrences you can't do it with a simple builtin function expression, but a simple user defined function can do the job.

```
create function dbo.MyTrim(@text varchar(max)) returns varchar(max)
as
-- function to remove all commas from the right end of the input.
begin

    while (right(@text, 1) = ','
    begin
        set @text = left(@text, len(@text) - 1)
    end

    return @text

end
go
```

Answer (score 2):

You can search for the first occurrence of `',,'` and take everything before that:

```
select (case when numbers like '%,,'
             then left(numbers, charindex(',,', numbers) - 1)
             when numbers like '%,'
             then left(numbers, len(numbers) - 1)
             else numbers
        end)
```

Note:  it would seem that you are storing lists of things in a comma-delimited string.  It is usually better to store these using a junction table.

EDIT:

Or, an alternative way of formulating this without the `case`:

```
select left(numbers + ',,', charindex(',,', numbers + ',,') - 1)
```

Comment: It yields result exceprt for **1,2,3,**

Comment: yes its fixed now. but not worked for this one **',,1,2,3,,,5,,'**. It's not case for me but just i said

Comment: @VigneshKumar . . . This question is specificallly "TrimEnd equivalent".  If you have a different question, you should ask it as a question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I think that is a legitimate comment. If he has a string `1,2,,3,,,5,,,,,` then simply finding the first occurrence of `,,` and stripping everything from that position isn't going to work. He would only want to trim the trailing commas.

Comment: @DavidFaber . . . That's fine.  It is just another question, to which this is not the answer.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2017 has implemented an enhanced version of TRIM function.
You can use TRIM(',' FROM '1,2,3,,,') to get the string, '1,2,3'

Comment: The question was before SQL 2017. But this is now the best answer, making the others obsolete. Works great for me.

Answer (score 0):

Run below query and get expected results

```
declare @sql varchar(500)

set @sql ='1,2,3,,,,,,'

select left(@sql,case charindex(',,',@sql,0)
when 0 then len(@sql)-1
else charindex(',,',@sql,0)-1
end)
```

Comment: What if @sql is '1,,2,3,,,,,,'?? It will return only 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create FUNCTION TrimStartEndAll 
(
    @string varchar(max),
    @trimValue varchar(5),
    @removeall int=0 
)

RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN

    if @removeall=1
    while  CHARINDEX(@trimValue,@string) >0 and @removeall=1
    begin
        set @string = REPLACE(@string,@trimValue,'')
    end
    if @removeall = 0
        begin

             while  CHARINDEX(@trimValue,@string) =1
                begin
                    set @string = SUBSTRING(@string,len(@trimValue)+1, len(@string))
                end

             while  substring(@string,len(@string)-len(@trimValue)+1, len(@trimValue)) = @trimValue
                begin
                    set @string =substring(@string,0, (len(@string)-len(@trimValue)+1))
                end
         end
    return @string
END
GO
```

output

```
select dbo.TrimStartEndAll( ',,1,2,3,,,5,,,,,,,,,',',,',1) => 1,2,3,5,
select dbo.TrimStartEndAll( ',,1,2,3,,,5,,,,,,,,,',',,',0) => 1,2,3,,,5,
```